# Pandas: Multi-Index Subset Selection

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

The following code will produce a dataframe that represents four players, each making multiple rolls of two dice:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
    list(['Alice', 'Alice', 'Alice', 
          'Bob', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Bob', 
          'Carol', 'Carol', 'Carol', 'Carol', 'Carol', 'Carol', 
          'Dan', 'Dan']),
    list('1231234512345612')
], names=['player', 'roll'])

#df = pd.DataFrame({'die1': np.random.randint(1, 7, len(mux)),
#                   'die2': np.random.randint(1, 7, len(mux))}, mux)

df = pd.DataFrame({'die1': ['3','6','2','1','1','6','5','1','3','1','4','5','3','5','5','5'],
                   'die2': ['2','5','1','4','1','6','3','5','6','4','5','1','4','4','3','6']}, mux)
```

This is the dataframe produced:

```
            die1 die2
player roll          
Alice  1       3    2
       2       6    5
       3       2    1
Bob    1       1    4
       2       1    1
       3       6    6
       4       5    3
       5       1    5
Carol  1       3    6
       2       1    4
       3       4    5
       4       5    1
       5       3    4
       6       5    4
Dan    1       5    3
       2       5    6
```

I am interested in the **players**-- not just the individual rolls, but the players-- who roll a 6 on the first die.

The following code does what I do not want, it returns the individual rolls where the first die is a 6:  `df[df.die1=='6']`:

```
             die1   die2
player  roll        
Alice   2    6      5
Bob     3    6      6
```

How can I produce the following, by using die1, without making mention of the individual player names, which I obviously won't know *a priori*?

```
            die1 die2
player roll          
Alice  1       3    2
       2       6    5
       3       2    1
Bob    1       1    4
       2       1    1
       3       6    6
       4       5    3
       5       1    5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `groupby`:

```
# is your data string '6' or integer 6
df[df['die1'].eq('6').groupby('player').transform('any')]
```

Output:

```
            die1 die2
player roll          
Alice  1       3    2
       2       6    5
       3       2    1
Bob    1       1    4
       2       1    1
       3       6    6
       4       5    3
       5       1    5
```

Comment: In the concrete example, it's a string; in a random example, it's an int; in the real world situation that this toy is illustrating, it would actually be a float and I would use greater than or equal to.

Comment: This does look like what I want, but can you explain what the "transform('any')" is doing?

Comment: Then change `eq('6')` into `ge(6)`. `transform('any')` is similar to `np.any`, that is checking if there is any `True` in the group, except that it *transforms* the result a series with the same length/indexing with the original. So for example, `Alice` has `die1` equals `3,6,2`, `transform('any')` return `True, True, True`. You can print that series to have some idea what it does.

Comment: Ahhh, yes I understand now.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
ll=[]
for i, j in df.groupby('player'):
    if len(j[j.die1==6])>0:
        ll.append(j)
return pd.concat(ll)
```